# task kworker/u8:0:5 blocked for more than 120 seconds

Tags: linux, archlinux

**Issue:** When network disconnects (user action (or) connectivity is down), machines goes unstable

**$ uname -a**
Linux beach 4.13.3-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Sep 21 20:33:16 CEST 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**Journal logs** - http://dpaste.com/1QESR64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug. Fixed in Kernel 4.13.5 which is now in testing . Or install linux-zen kernel.